# Shell script: how to show the lines which second column is 10?

Tags: bash

I have a file,the content of which is like:

```
/media/data2tb2/NYKPProcessing/IE_copora/2006/03/26/1749806.xml.json    4
/media/data2tb2/NYKPProcessing/IE_copora/2006/09/17/1790533.xml.json    4
```

Is there a simple way to show the lines which second column is 10?

Comment: `awk '$2 == 10' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk`, like this:

```
cat file.txt |awk '{if ($2 == 10) print $0;}'
```